# T4 can't reference own project's assembly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, .net-assembly, t4

In T4, I simply want to reference my own project's assembly. As per instructions online I tried the following:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)" #>
```

followed by:

```
<#@ import namespace="LazyDeploy" #>
```

For your reference, here is my solution structure:

[image: Project]

Other than the `HTMLFactory` namespace, everything is scoped to the `LazyDeploy` namespace. I also tried taking the template into the root of the solution to no avail. The error is as follows:

```
An exception was thrown while trying to compile the transformation code. The following Exception was thrown:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\users\kmalton\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\LazyDeploy\LazyDeploy\bin\Debug\'.
File name: 'c:\users\kmalton\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\LazyDeploy\LazyDeploy\bin\Debug\' ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\users\kmalton\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\LazyDeploy\LazyDeploy\bin\Debug\'.
```

I am not sure why this is the case as the directory exists, i.e. I can cut and paste directly from the stack trace into explorer and navigate there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to be reference the dll directly as part of the assembly declaration:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)LazyDeploy.dll" #>
```